# '(Cannot run program "make": Launching failed) .' in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse for Windows and have this error:

> **Build of configuration Debug for project helloworld**
>   (Cannot run program "make": Launching failed)

What do I do to solve this?

Comment: I am adding a bounty because I would like an answer for Windows 8.1 and Eclipse Kepler or Luna.

Answer (score 9):

Eclipse CDT on Windows depends on 3rd party tools.

You may find this useful: [Setting up a compiler](http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/ar01s03.jsp#wincompiler)

Comment: +1 I was having the same problem as the OP. The instructions on this page solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem while installing Eclipse for c/c++ applications .I downloaded **Mingw GCC** ,put its bin folder in your **path** ,used it in **toolchains** while making new C++ project in Eclipse and **build** which solved my problem. Referred to this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0yNvQZvatBA)