# Launch Failed. Binary not found. CDT on Eclipse Helios

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse Helios on Ubuntu 10.04, and I'm trying to install CDT plugin on it. I download it from here [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/cdt/releases/helios/dist/cdt-master-7.0.1.zip).

And then I go to **Install New Software** and select the zip file (*I don't extract it, just select the zip file*). And its ok, it installs, everything works fine, it shows optional features, *blah blah blah*.

And then I create a new HelloWorld project. And when I try to run it, it shows an error and says:

Launch failed. Binary not found.

Can anyone explain me how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: On MacOSX I had the same problem: after building the project it wouldn't run and it gave me the message: "Launch failed. Binary not found." I solved it by going to `Run > Run Configurations... > C/C++ Application > {path to executable}`

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis : I had this problem too, and solved in this way too. But even if the path still shows in the configuration, somehow I always had to go to the path and then click run instead of `run as local c/c++ application`. could u help?

Comment: @user2751691 I'm sorry, I can't think of something (besides I'm currently not using MacOSX). Let me know how you solved it though if you find something...

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis : I solved it by changing the binary parser from elf parser to Mach O 64 parser. then it magically worked. Thanks.

Comment: Binary Parser ELF would be in Ubuntu / Linux. In mac your build binary parser should be Mach-O. See https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/268200/ I've added an answer

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You must build an executable file before you can run it. So if you don't “BUILD” your file, then it will not be able to link and load that object file, and hence it does not have the required binary numbers to execute.

So basically right click on the `Project -> Build Project -> Run As Local C/C++ Application` should do the trick

Comment: I built the project but it gives error even for #include <stdio.h> I get a unresolved inclusion what should I do?

Comment: Although I followed this step but it was not working for me and the reason was, I didn't save the file itself.

Comment: Thx @varunthacker, after a long struggle, your answer fixed my problem, simple and efficient!

Comment: I don't think this is the better answer.  The problem could be because it was not built, a file was not saved, the incorrect parser was chosen.  This only addresses one problem.

Answer (score 36):

First you need to make sure that the project has been built. You can build a project with the hammer icon in the toolbar. You can choose to build either a Debug or Release version. If you cannot build the project then the problem is that you either don't have a compiler installed or that the IDE does not find the compiler.

To see if you have a compiler installed in a Mac you can run the following command from the command line:

```
g++ --version
```

If you have it already installed (it gets installed when you install the XCode tools) you can see its location running:

```
which g++
```

If you were able to build the project but you still get the "binary not found" message then the issue might be that a default launch configuration is not being created for the project. In that case do this:

```
Right click project > Run As > Run Configurations... >
```

Then create a new configuration under the "C/C++ Application" section > Enter the full path to the executable file (the file that was created in the build step and that will exist in either the Debug or Release folder). Your launch configuration should look like this:

[image]

Comment: How can I force eclipse to create this `Run Configurations` by default? I do not have this problem by eclipse in Windows.

Answer (score 16):

Go to the **Run->Run Configuration->** now

Under C/C++ Application you will see the name of your executable + Debug (if not, click over C/C++ Application a couple of times). Select the name (in this case  **projectTitle+Debug**).

Under this in **main Tab ->  C/C++ application -> Search your project** -> in binaries select your **binary titled by your project**....

Comment: @Unmesh : Hi, in my project, I have to manually browse there to set up the location every time I want to run the project. Is there a way to make it remember the location please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420749/eclipse-cdt-cannot-find-built-exe-file-after-building-have-to-click-run-configu   Thank you.

Comment: Problem in my case was also that even _after_ building Eclipse said it could not find the binaries. Turns out that the run config was missing. Thanks!

Comment: @Unmesh
How can I force eclipse to create this Run Configurations by default? I do not have this problem by eclipse in Windows.

Answer (score 4):

You must "build" before "run", otherwise "Binary not found". You can set up "Auto build", so that it will build and run. Check this post to set up "Auto build" http://situee.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-set-eclipse-cdt-auto-build.html

Comment: I fixed the binary path issue, but my C project still wouldn't run... until I read your answer and realized I hadn't rebuilt the project since I had fixed the binary path issue!  Thanks.  Sometimes I just need the obvious pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem for a long while and I couldn't figure out the answer. I had added all the paths, built everything and pretty much followed what everyone on here had suggested, but no luck.

Finally I read the comments and saw that there were some compilation errors that were aborting the procedure before the binaries and exe file was generated.

Bottom line: Do a code review and make sure that there are no errors in your code because sometimes eclipse will not always catch everything.

If you can run a basic hello world but not your code then obviously something is wrong with your code. I learned the hard way.

Answer (score 4):

If you still have an error even after building the project then try to do this:

- click on *Binaries* in Project Explorer with the left button
- click on green "Play" button (Run  Debug)

Comment: Awesome. It also remebers the selection so Run from the menu will subsequentially work.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same problem and found the solution in the anwser to another question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1951132/425749

Basically, installing CDT does not install a compiler, and Eclipse's error messages are not explicit about this.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. I have Eclipse Indigo and Eclipse Luna on Ubuntu. I tried many solutions, but none worked. Here's how you can try :)
Try it in order :)

1. Either do Build All and then compile :)
2. Install G++ Compiler
3. Windows->Preferences->NEW CDT PRoject-> Makefile-> Binary Parsers-> Choose Cywin or Window PE depending on your Os :)
4. Change your toolchain to cywin gcc
5. Project->Properties->Environment-> Release Active

After 1,2, 3, and 4, I tried changing paths, and other stuff, but nothing worked. In the end, I noticed that it mentioned Debug Active was not configured. So when I changed it to Release Active, it worked. Do note that change in environment and path is not required.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem while installing Eclipse for c/c++ applications .I downloaded **Mingw GCC** ,put its bin folder in your **path** ,used it in toolchains while making new C++ project in Eclipse and **build** which solved my problem.
Referred to this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0yNvQZvatBA)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like having "Build Automatically" under the Project menu ought to take care of all of this. It does for Java.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have GDB installed on your system...

If your using Linux based OS simply in  a terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get install gdt
```

when finished downloading extract the file and install.

close your IDE (in this case eclipse and open it again and run your project.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the compiler to the PATH fixed the problem for me...

```
export PATH="$HOME/opt/cross/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the same as one commenter above. I had to change the binary parser to the correct one (PE for windows, ELF for Linux, mach for mac)