# Eclipse - C++ hello world project's error

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows-7, binary

I am using a 64-bit Winodws 7. I've downloaded a `CDT` `Eclipse` and have downloaded `MinGW`. After that, I created a c++ hello world project.
This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // This is supposed to print "Hello World!!!"
    return 0;
}
```

But when I want to run it, this error pops up:
"Launch failed. `Binary not found`."

Any help would be highly welcomed.

Comment: does your project compile? :)

Comment: Seems similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971926/launch-failed-binary-not-found-cdt-on-eclipse-helios

Comment: @forsvarir There is no answer there

Comment: Rather long winded dicussion about setting up eclipse for windows can be found here (apparently it doesn't always recognise .EXE as executable or something): http://codingrecipes.com/eclipse-launch-failed-binary-not-found-and-netbeans

Comment: It is not helpful. I read it.

Comment: That's quite the bold statement, "it is not helpful". Instead of shifting blame, perhaps try harder to understand.

Comment: It takes more effort to get Eclipse C/C++ to work in Windows, than it does to manipulate strings in C, screw it. I'm using Dev-C++ from Bloodshed. I'll use Eclipse for Java.

Comment: @Pete Herbert Penito: I would recommend to use Visual C++ Express. It is ready just right away after being installed.

Answer (score 3):

You have to "Build" your project before you can "Run" it.
When using Eclipse for Java, you simply click the "Run" icon, then Eclipse will automaticly compile your program and then run it.
With C++ however, this is for whatever reason not the case. Instead of just clicking the "Run" icon, you need to click the "Build" icon first. This is where Eclipse will create a makefile and compile your program. Then you can run it by clicking the "Run" icon.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I now get an error saying: Launching test Debug has encountered a problem Error starting process

Answer (score 2):

Has eclipse built the EXE file correctly for you? Look for helloworld.exe or whatever, and try running it from a Windows Command prompt.

If not, then you've got a problem with your build. Build it again and check for errors.

If the EXE file is there, but cannot be run from within Eclipse then check that the [PE Windows Binary Parser](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_proj_parser.htm) is enabled for your project.

**UPDATE**:  To fix "Unresolved Inclusion" errors, [see here.](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=657331&S=e6a9de531b51dd4203a997829bea785f) In particular, try this:

> 1. Right-click on the probject and select "Properties"
> 2. Go to "C/C++ General" -> "Paths and Symbols" and select "Includes" tab
> 3. Select "GNU C++"
> 4. Press on "Add..."
> 5. Look for the folder "C:\dev\eclipse\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1-dw2\include\c++"
>      or similar

**UPDATE** See also this link:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#I_am_using_a_non_gnu_compiler_and_I_get_the_following_messages:_.22Error_launching_external_scanner_info_generator_.28gcc_-E_-P_-v_-dD.22_and_.22File_not_indexed_because_it_was_not_built_.22._How_do_I_get_rid_of_them.3F

Comment: @Roddy There is no exe file there. There is a error. Unresoleved inclussion. IOStream

Comment: have you set up the paths to the include files?

Comment: I did that. That is solved. But there is another error. Description Resource Path Location Type
Error launching external scanner info generator (gcc -E -P -v -dD C:/Users/Mahtab/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.cpp)

Comment: @Masoud. Google is *my* friend. Try and make it yours also!

Comment: @Roddy: I used google. I tried lots of ways but nothing worked.

Comment: @Masoud - please take the time to SAY IN YOUR QUESTION what you've tried, and what happened. We're not mind-readers, and the better your question, the more chance you'll have of getting useful answers. Also, "Nothing worked" isn't helpful. What error message are you getting now?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because you Windows is 64 bit and Eclipse just sort of chooses to ignore executables in this format without reporting any error. Pretty convenient, huh? Try this to fix it:

Right-click your project -> Properties -> expand "MinGW C++ Liker" in the right side pane and select the **Miscellaneous** option

Under "Other options" you will add a new option:

```
-arch=i386
```

Rebuild your application, refresh, and you should see a **Binaries** folder that contains your executable. You can run it by going to Run As -> Local C/C++ Application

Comment: A bit late :), but I had to search to find the MinGW C++ LINKER location. For anyone else looking, the MinGW C++ Linker (not Liker) is in              project > properties > C/C++ Build > Settings

Answer (score 0):

First check the toolchain selected,while creating the new c++ project.It should be MinGW as you have stated,(hope you have made the entries in the environmental variables).Write the code .press ctrl+b to build the workspace. Rt click the project and select clean project.press f5 to refresh.then ctrl+f11 to run your prg.Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select the correct Toolchain when you create the project.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This happens due to windows execution permission (I assume that you're running eclipse from an external drive or from another partition), if you run eclipse as an administrator you will be able to debug your application without problems..