# "Launch failed. Binary not found." error on CDT Kepler Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, mingw32

Running or debugging anything gives me an extremely frustrating "Launch failed. Binary not found" error. I'm using Eclipse with a CDT plugin installed (specifically, I have the MinGW package installed).

I already tried setting both the user and system PATH variables to include my (MinGW directory)/bin

I also tried building the program before running it.

I also made sure that PE Windows Parser under the project's settings was enabled.

I went to Project Properties > Run/Debug Settings > New > C/C++ Application > Environment > Select > and I selected the Path

I also tried setting the C/C++ Application in the Main tab to the executable file that is made from building the program, but no such file is made when I do build my program. I seriously doubt that this is what's causing the problem, though.

I'm running out of options, and the problem still persists. What else needs to be done? What am I doing wrong?

When I was looking through the install instructions for MinGW, the tutorial referenced the mingw base package as the package to install after installing MinGW. But mingw base was not available to me. Instead, I saw mingw32 base. Could it be that Eclipse, a 64 bit program, is trying to run 32 bit code? Is that what's going on? If that's the problem, how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you tried this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971926

Answer (score 10):

1. Build
2. Refresh the project. A new folder named Binaries will appear now in project explorer.
3. Now Run :)

Answer (score 2):

It took me 3 days to figure out my problem.  My Hello World C program would compile in eclipse using the Windows PE Parser, but there was NO EXE FILE!!!!  AVAST Antivirus was identifying the exe file as a false positive and removing it....grrrrr. The solution was to add the eclipse workspace folder to the exclusions list.  Voila!! Eclipse generated my test.exe file.

Answer (score 1):

save the file first before you build and run... it works with me

Answer (score 1):

Check the compiler you set while you created the project . If that is MINGW or Visual Studio ; check whether they are downloaded or not . If not do so and start a new project by closing the old one . Build the new project by pressing Ctrl + B and a new file 'Binaries' is created in the package explorer . Now you can use the run option to run the project .

Answer (score -1):

First the solution: install "make"

I had the same issue.

I also tried the steps you did with no luck.

After some time i found a the solution!

The problem was that i did not have the application "make".

Apparently its not installed by default on Cygwin and eclipse doesn't give any indication for that...