# Eclipse C++ Setup, Path to executable not set

Tags: c++, eclipse

I try to program some stuff in c++ with eclipse, but I have slight difficulties.
When I create a new Project compiling and making works fine but when I try to run the Application I get the following error message:

"Launch failed. Binary not found"

So what I found out by using google is this workaround:
-right-click on the projekt in the projekt explorer
-select "run as" and then "run configurations"
-expand "c/c++ application" in the navbar on the left
-and in the main tab of the project select "browse"
-navigate to folder "debug" and select the .exe

after I do that, running works fine but I have to do it again every time I create a new Project, is there a way to automate this process?

And what I also noticed: I don't have a "binaries" folder in my projects in the project explorer, maybe its related to that, but I really don't know.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks
Tim

Edit: added a video: http://youtu.be/RKnTOkoHFRU

Comment: Duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407430

Comment: no. it does work fine if i use the workaround, tried all the answers to the question you posted but still no "binaries" folder and i still have to select the .exe every time i create a new project. but thanks for the effort

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch Failed. Binary not found. CDT on Eclipse Helios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971926/launch-failed-binary-not-found-cdt-on-eclipse-helios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open project properties (Right click on your project, choose Properties on the menu)
2. C/C++ Build -> Settings
3. Click on Binary Parsers tab and check PE Windows Parser

as seen here [stackoverflow.com/questions/9407430](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407430), answer number 3 or 4

Answer (score 1):

There will only be a `Binaries` folder if the build was successful. You will have to manually build to get a binary in order for the `Binaries` folder to appear. Likewise, if you `clean` (remove) your build folder then `Binaries` will disappear.

I would guess that Eclipse cannot find your binary "out-of-the-box" because you are using external tools to manage the build process; that is, if you have a custom makefile project (or another type of project that uses another tool to handle the building) then Eclipse will not be able to provide a default run configuration because it does not "know" where the binary is or even which binary to run if there are multiple. Thus, you have to set up the Run Configuration as you are doing now.

If you create a project and let Eclipse do the building, then Eclipse can find the binaries automatically. For example, simply create an "Empty C++ Project" under "Executable". Write some hello world code. Click build. Then click run. Eclipse launches the binary because it is managing the build process and thus "knows about" where the binary ends up.

Comment: I added a video, maybe that shows whats causing the problem. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

In my case

1. I just save the programme. Press **CTRL+B** to build it.
2. Refresh it.
3. Then run the programme.

Now you can see this will work fine.

I have already answered this for other question see the link [Launch Failed Binary not found Eclipse for C in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407430/launch-failed-binary-not-found-eclipse-for-c-in-windows) at 10th number.