# Eclipse CDT cannot find built exe file after building, have to click run configuration

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, binaryfiles, run-configuration

I am using Eclipse CDT. I encounter a really weird problem.

After I built a project, I click on the project and choose `run as` -> `local c/c++ project`, it will throw a `binary not found` error. If I right click the project -> `run configuration`, but does not make any changes or touch any buttons, and click `Run`, it compiles and runs perfectly... So everytime, I have to click the `run configurations`, and then hit run. I also have the `auto-build` option on in the properties.

Does anyone have an idea please?

Thank you.