# How to run a c/c++ application in eclipse for c/c++

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to run an application from eclipse IDE.
And I have installed cygwin compiler on my system.
Whenever I try to run an application from the eclipse IDE I reeceive an error as 
    Launch Failed.Binary Not Found.

Comment: Please have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971926/launch-failed-binary-not-found-cdt-on-eclipse-helios

Comment: I have found the answer to this question.Actually,I just tried to run the application without building the project.So now I am able to run the application in eclipse cdt.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually **Launch Failed.Binary Not Found.** error happens when we try to run the application without building the project.

So,to get rid of this error just right click on your project and click on build project.

And you will notice that a folder named binaries appear in the project directory.Now run the project.

Your application will run as expected.