# eclipse: Error - The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches

Tags: c++, eclipse

[The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOCqu.jpg)

At the end of this windows there is an error message about PATH. Please take a look: 
[MAKE PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeSd8.jpg)
The Program what I tried to run:

```
#include <iostream>
int main ()
 cout<<"Hello World!";

 return 0;
}
```

When I click on the 'Play' button/ Run command, it keeps showing this disgusting-annoying error message.

What could be the solution?

I check another articles where they stated that it has a problem with 'main ()' 
but it is not missing from my code.

Now the full code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
 cout << "Hello World!";

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Format your code correctly please (indent every code line with four spaces). Also take a look at all the other error messages appearing with the 1st version of your program.

Comment: You're missing a `{` in your `main` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['(Cannot run program "make": Launching failed) .' in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950974/cannot-run-program-make-launching-failed-in-eclipse)

Comment: Thank you guys your answers!